# How do I add multiple audio files (filtering one) to a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, git-bash

I am trying to mute a video and add two audio files to it.  One is voice narration, the second is music filtered down to .5 its usual volume.

I see that I get an error message that I can't combine the -filter with -c:a, but deleting the -c:a does not help.  The audio gets added no problem, but filtering does not work.

`ffmpeg -ss $START -i "$VIDEO" -i "$AUDIO1" -i "$AUDIO2" -filter:a "volume=1.5" -t $AUDIOLENGTH -map 0:v -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest "./Output/${AUDIONAME}/${AUDIONAME}.mp4" -y`

This code I have seems to only merge one audio file in.  On top of that, if I edit it to only have one audio file added in, the -filter switch does not seem to be working.  Please help, it's getting so aggravating!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to filter multiple inputs in some combination, a filtergraph must be used, invoked via -filter_complex. In this particular use, the amix filter can be used.

`ffmpeg -ss $START -i "$VIDEO" -i "$AUDIO1" -i "$AUDIO2" -filter_complex "[1][2]amix=inputs=2:weights='2 1'[a]" -t $AUDIOLENGTH -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "./Output/${AUDIONAME}/${AUDIONAME}.mp4" -y`

(If you're supplying output duration `-t`, -shortest can be removed)

Comment: Thank you, but I get

`[Parsed_amix_0 @ 0000020eacceee40] Option 'weights' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020eac8fcac0] Error initializing filter 'amix' with args 'inputs=2:weights=2 1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found`

when I run that with the filter_complex

Comment: Got it to work:

`ffmpeg -ss $START -i "$VIDEO" -i "$AUDIO1" -i "$AUDIO2" -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=2[a1]; [2:a]volume=0.1[a2]; [a1][a2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -t $AUDIOLENGTH -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "./Output/${AUDIONAME}/${AUDIONAME}.mp4" -y`

Comment: weights option was added in ffmpeg 4.0